# Using npm link returns error "Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/"

Tags: npm, npm-link

I am trying to link a local dependency of scss styles to a project using `npm link`. Following the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link) I run `npm link` in the dependencies directory, which tells me:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/xxx/xyz -> /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xyz

The I got to my project directory and run `npm link xyz` but it give the error:

> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xyz - Not found

So it is not finding the symlink and searching npm.

I have read that this can be caused by using `nvm` with different versions of node but this is not the case for me.

How can I successfully link the package?

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

You can link the package manually:

###### `pacakge.json`

```
  "package": "package@*"
```

###### Project that requires the dependency

> create a symbolic link to the local dependency

```
cd node_modules
ln -nfs ../relative/path/to/local/package
```